# Getting angularJS $http.post from nodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Please help me, I would like to get angularJS $http.post parameter that being sent to be processed in nodeJS.

I would like to see whether the parameter (nama, nip, pernr, etc...) was sent successfully, but the result is undefined as shown below :

**angularJS code :**

```
// ADMINISTRATOR ========================================
.state('talentapegawai.uploadtalenta.douploadtalenta', {
    views:{
         "monitorupload": { 
            url: '/douploadtalenta',
            templateUrl: '/progressupload.html',
            controller:function($scope, $http, XLSXReaderService){
                $scope.prograssing2 = true;
                for(var i=0; i < $scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName].length; i++){
                    $http.post("/execuploadtalenta",{'nama': $scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].nama, 'nip': $scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].nip, 'pernr':$scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].pernr, 'tgl_grade_terakhir': $scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].tgl_grade, 'singkatan_talenta': $scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].talenta_abbr, 'talenta': $scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].talenta, 'mulai':$scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].mulai, 'akhir':$scope.sheets[$scope.selectedSheetName][i].akhir})
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                            console.log("inserted Successfully");
                    });
                }
                $scope.prograssing2 = false;
            }
        }
    }   
})
```

**NodeJS code (express) :**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.post('/execuploadtalenta', requireLogin, function (req, res) {
        console.log("NILAI REQUEST : "+req.body.nama); -->return undefined
        console.log("NILAI REQUEST : "+req); -->return [object, object]
    });

server.listen(3333);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, Tell body-parser to parse json requests:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
```

Its also a good practice to limit the size of json objects
Then, You should be able to read the body as a JSON object.
Take a troubleshooting tip, just to make sure what you get in the body is correct, you can print it as string:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

Comment: Nice, really helpful. Thanks a lot @buddy123